# Definitions of the word "delete" vs. public understanding of the word?

Tags: meaning, expressions, computing

I just asked a [question on User Experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/94316/is-this-message-misleading-to-users), involving the word *delete*. This English question is based on that UX question, so its motive can be understood better by reading both questions.

It seems to me that the word *delete* has a twofold meaning in English.
I found this on Wiktionary:

> 1. To remove, get rid of or erase, especially written or printed material, or data on a computer.
> 2. *(computing)* To hide, conceal

#1 seems to suggest that the information is permanently destroyed, while #2 suggests the data is only concealed.

How do strict definitions of the word in computing and non-computing contexts differ from the way the general public typically understands the word?

How is the word typically understood by common, non-technical people, in a personal computing context?

As for the message quoted on UX SE, if anyone has a suggestion for it, I encourage them to head over there and post it. :)

Comment: Yes, good question:http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7996/deleted-answers-vs-deleted-questions?cb=1

Comment: Most computer operations are make-believe. The "delete" command does remove, but only the address to the data and not the data itself. However, the effect is to release the storage space for new data and when such new data replaces the "deleted" data, the latter gets physically over-written and is lost. Summarily, there's no issue of different meanings only one of usage. The dictionary's separation is for reader convenience -- it does not mean a contradiction/ variance. HTH.

Comment: cf. above, this question rightly belongs on [UX.se] where it's originally asked, not on ELU.

Comment: @Kris I think there's an overlap between the two sites. I figured I'd find more expertise regarding the language aspects here. Also, I'm asking for different things in each question.

Comment: @Kris - I am nor sure that over-written deleted data is totally  unrecoverable.

Comment: @Josh61 That has been discussed many times on Security SE and there have been some excellent answers pointing out both sides of the debate.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You should have said "knock on wood". :)

Comment: Just shows how unpredictable viewers/users are! The question sounded nerdy. I like the question, and it deserves more attention.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks :) I guess the title wasn't clickbaity enough :)

Comment: I disagree with the #2 definition. Although *hiding* of information often happens on deletion in the context of operating systems, I think this is an implementation detail, not part of the proper semantics of the word. The reverse process is called *recovery* (or *undelete*), not *show*. It's akin to writing on a piece of paper, erasing the pencil mark, then using the remaining indentations to recover the original word - the intention is permanent removal, even though retrieval methods exist. *Hiding* and *concealment* are quite different semantically from *deletion*.

Comment: @Lawrence In database contexts, deleting data often actually removes it from view but it doesn't actually get removed from anywhere (it can be as simple as setting a "deleted" flag on a record, or simply the presence of the data in journals or logs. You might call it an implementation detail, but often there are legal, functional or architectural requirements that necessitate keeping the actual data. This is still called deletion, even though users are often aware that their data is only "hidden". A dictionary definition is _not_ a list of actual synonyms!

Comment: @oerkelens It's the intent / semantic that's important here. If the user considers it expunged (even if it can be brought back), then it has been *deleted*. If the user thinks of it as simply put away, it has been *archived*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the idea of ***[deleting](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/delete.htm)***  in computing is based on the notion that a text or else can be later recovered in case of need. That is  a very different concept from the more common notion we have of deleting something, that is destroy  something so  that it cannot be recovered.

> - In general, delete or remove refers to the act of eliminating a file, text, or other object from the computer hard drive or other media. Files deleted in Microsoft Windows are sent to the Recycling Bin. On Apple computers, deleted files are sent to the Trash. ***In most operating systems, when files are deleted, they are only marked as such, but still exist on the hard drive until they are overwritten by other data. This condition is what makes data recovery possible.***

(computerhope.com/jargon)

Comment: +1.  No wonder people get confused.

Comment: +1 Yes, this "soft delete" vs "hard delete" on websites is something I only recently discovered myself (about a year or more so)

Comment: Deleting a file on a computer is akin to erasing the words "DO NOT ERASE!!" from a whiteboard.  It just gives the system the permission to actually delete it should it want to.

Answer (score 1):

I think the view that the non-computer use of *delete* means obliterate completely with no possibility of reinstatement is not supported by most  definitions

> 1. Remove or obliterate (written or printed matter), especially by drawing a line through it or marking it with a delete sign:
>      *the passage was deleted*
>
>    1.1 (usually be deleted) Remove (data) from a computer’s memory.
>
>    1.2 (be deleted) Genetics (Of a section of genetic code, or its product) be lost or excised from a nucleic acid or protein sequence:
>      *if one important gene is deleted from an animal’s DNA, other genes can stand in*
>
>    1.3 Remove (a product, especially a recording) from the catalog of those available for purchase:
>      *their EMI release has already been deleted*

*[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/delete)*

In the initial definition,the use of strikethrough or a symbol to show deletion does not permanently or completely negate the deleted material. It merely says *don't use* at this time.

The computing definition says remove from memory, but computers have many types and locations for memory, and deletion from one type or area does not preclude retention elsewhere.

The genetic *delete* does seem (to this non-scientist) as fairly permanent.

the removal of an item from a catalog surely does not preclude the inclusion at some later date.

Definitions in other sources are similar

> 1a. To cancel, strike out, or make impossible to be perceived: *deleted the expletives from the transcript with a marker.*
>
> b. To remove from a document or record: *deleted the names from the computer file.* See Synonyms at erase.
>
> 2. To remove (a file, for example) from a hard drive or other storage medium.

*[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=delete)*